# nodejs bip39 seed with hdkey.fromMasterSeed

Tags: ethereum

I am running into a weird error while trying to implement bip39/bip32. I've tried both the hdkey library and hdkey from ethereumjs-wallet and both fail with the same error when I try to do hdkey.fromMasterSeed where the master seed is a buffer returned from bip39 lib's mnemonicToSeedSync function.
For some reason, I am getting this error:

> Expected private key to be an Uint8Array
>
> 28 |
> 29 | const seed = mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
> 30 | const hdWallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
> | ^
> 31 | const wallet = hdWallet
> 32 | .derivePath(EthereumECIES.primaryKeyDerivationPath)
> 33 | .getWallet();
>
> at assert (../../node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:18:20)
> at isUint8Array (../../node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:22:3)
> at Object.privateKeyVerify (../../node_modules/secp256k1/lib/index.js:66:7)
> at Object.privateKeyVerify (../../node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/src/shims/hdkey-secp256k1v3.ts:4:20)
> at HDKey.set (../../node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:46:26)
> at Function.Object..HDKey.fromMasterSeed (../../node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/vendor/hdkey-without-crypto.js:194:20)
> at Function.fromMasterSeed (../../node_modules/ethereumjs-wallet/src/hdkey.ts:13:36)
> at Function.generateKeyPairFromMnemonic (src/lib/cryptoWallet.ts:30:28)
> at Object. (src/lib/cryptoWallet.spec.ts:8:29)

Any ideas why this is happening? It is a typescript project in an nx monorepo with node 20

I've tried the hdkey library and the hdkey from ethereumjs-wallet and both run into exactly the same problem. I'm confident I've got a Buffer coming out of the mnemonicToSeedSync function via step-debugging.

It seems like there is an incompatibility somewhere in the child dependencies. I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Did you solve it? Please share reproducible example code